# Image response in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-imaging-library, python-2.7

I am saving a user's image as a BlobProperty by doing:

```
user.image = urlfetch.fetch(image_url).content
```

Then I'm rendering that image using a url such as:

```
/image/user_id
```

The image must be saving because because when I do len(user.image) I get a number in the thousands. And on the local instance the image renders ok. On the deployed app, I get the following error, and when I go to the image url nothing shows in the browser:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
self.finish_response()
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
self.write(data)
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 202, in write
assert type(data) is StringType,"write() argument must be string"
AssertionError: write() argument must be string`

Also, here's the handler that serves the image:

```
class ImageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
""" Returns image based on id. """
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = db.get(
        db.Key.from_path('User', models.User.get_key_name(kwargs.get('id'))))
    if user.image:
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/jpeg"
        self.response.out.write(user.image)
    else:
        self.response.out.write("No image")
```

Just to clarify I tried both setting content-type to jpeg and png. And things are working ok on the local server. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the property type of user.image?

Comment: A better way would also be to store the urlfetch'd data in the blobstore, and use `images.get_serving_url()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's db.BlobProperty. Blobstore will add another level of complexity - these are small avatar images of twitter users.

Comment: You probably need to update your question to include (at least) the handler you're using to serve the image.

Comment: The blobstore will just be a different level of complexity, perhaps not even greater. However, the images will be served off of google's high performance image servers, and not cost you instance hours like any other solution would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question, that fixes everything:

```
self.response.out.write(str(user.image))
```

It's confusing because the example in the docs does not cast the BlobProperty as string.

Answer (score 2):

Why not write the image to the blobstore and then use the send_blob() mechanism?

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob